# Detecting the same external hdd

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I mounted an external ntfs drive on my ubuntu server.
Since it's an external hdd at night I unplugged it and when I plugged it back in ubuntu didn't detect the already mounted hdd :(

This is what I did to mount the hdd:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/discoexterno1/
```

This worked great. I even shared it with my windows machine, but since I unplugged it and plugged back I can't access it. Every time I do:

```
ls /mnt/discoexterno1
```

I get:

```
ls: cannot access /mnt/discoexterno1: Input/output error
```

What can I do to make ubuntu server associate automatically the directory with the hdd?

This is everything I have in the dev directory starting with s

/dev/scd0  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdd1  /dev/sde1  /dev/sg1  /dev/sg3  /dev/snapshot  /dev/sr0     /dev/stdin
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdc   /dev/sdd   /dev/sde   /dev/sg0   /dev/sg2  /dev/sg4  /dev/sndstat   /dev/stderr  /dev/stdout

/dev/shm:

/dev/snd:
controlC0  pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D0p  pcmC0D1c  pcmC0D1p  timer

I also have 2 other external hdd but I only mounted one to test this. (I am a newbie)

So, do I have to keep mounting the hdd everytime I unplug and plug it?? Or is there some way (by detecting the serial number or something) that I can tell ubuntu server that I have mounted that hdd??

Thanks

Comment: The words you need to look up are "udev" which is used to create the devices and uuid which is an identifier for the disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should unmount the drive before you unplug it, and mount it when you plug it in.  If you want to make this happen automatically you can use something like [autofs](http://www.linux-consulting.com/Amd_AutoFS/autofs.html).  If you want to make this work nicely you probably should set a label for the filesystem and mount based on the label.